# Sql query to find the location where conitnous use of cabs utilization between 2 dates

Tags: mysql

Sql query to find the location where conitnous use of cabs utilization between 2 dates

`cab_pool` table

```
cabid,date,available_cabs,used_cabs
1,10/16/2010,25,5
1,11/16/2010,20,9
1,12/16/2010,20,13
2,10/16/2010,15,3
2,11/16/2010,14,4
2,12/16/2010,20,6
3,10/16/2010,15,5
3,11/16/2010,14,4
3,12/16/2010,20,6
```

`cab_location` Table2

```
cabid,city_name
1,Central park
2,Times square
3,Empire state building
```

Expected out

```
city_name
Central park
```

Comment: Have you tried any query yet?

Comment: What do you mean by continuous use of cabs? all the cabs are used for 3 consecutive months. so why you want only `central park`?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy from central park people used maximum cabs on average

Comment: @sim In that case just take `avg()` of available cabs group by `cabid` and then the maximum from that. But Let's just wait for OP's response though

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy as like sim told `from central park people used maximum cabs on average`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below query

```
select max(cl.city_name) as cityname
from cabpool c JOIN cablocation cl on c.cabid= cl.cabid
group by c.cabid
order by avg(c.used_cabs) desc
limit 1
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e8a1399f4f12582a987b1eb23b1fdf8)

*Explanation* : 
We can get the maximum of average by using `order by` and `limit` like below:

```
select cabid,avg(used_cabs) avgused
from cabpool  
group by cabid
order by avgused desc
limit 1
```

Then you can join with the `cablocation` table to get the `city_name` as shown in the first query.